# Xamarin Studio 6 incompatible with NUnit 3.2.1

Tags: xamarin, nunit

I've downloaded the latest copy of xamarin studio which is 6.0 build 3668. I've built a tiny console app and I'm trying to run some unit tests through the UI in xamarin, but I get a message saying that nunit 3.2.1 is unsupported. I have a fake script which does work when run in the terminal.

Full error message is here : Skipped loading assembly test because it references an unsupported version of the nunit.framework, 3.2.1.0.

Can anyone help please ?

Comment: Is your test project a PCL library? If so, switch it to .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the problem: "*Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NUnit' could not be found*".
It's because the .dll file is not loaded in the references of the solution.

In my case, I am using [Monodevelop/Xamarin Studio 7.8.4](https://www.monodevelop.com/download/),
having multiple NUnit dlls in the monodevelop.UnitTest directory.
Duo to this reason, I had to add reference manually.

As I am using the [Ubuntu 18.04](https://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/) distribution, the nunit.framework.dll assembly was locketed at: usr/lib/monodevelop/Addins/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting/NUnit2/nunitframework.dll

So, I just added this assembly to the my project and the unit test was working fine.
Note: here I have added nunit.framework [2.6.4](https://github.com/nunit/nunitv2/releases/download/2.6.4/NUnit-2.6.4-net-1.1.zip) assembly.